# What are the options for an encrypted transport

Tags: encryption, tcp, udp, transport

I am working on an application that needs to encrypt all of its traffic on a LAN environment and so the speed of encryption is important and the cpu time needs to be reduced to let the application have more cpu cycles for itself. I am thus trying to understand what are my existing options besides rolling my own since I'm not a cryptographer.

I am trying to go now for a comprehensive list of all semi-valid options to be able to measure and test them:

- TLS -- Not considered fast, maybe possible to tune the ciphers
- SSH -- Maintaining ssh tunnels may be a burden
- UDT -- Should be high performance, how is the optional encryption?
- CurveCP -- By DJB so encryption is good, not sure about the transport part
- MinimaLT -- DJB contributed crypto know-how, others did the transport
- IPSec -- non-trivial to configure

What else I missed?

Comment: TLS is 'not considered fast' by whom? If you really have a major CPU usage problem you should look into a hardware solution, not a different protocol.

Comment: The preference is not to use an hardware solution, I can go with a limited use for CPU based hardware acceleration but can't expect my cloud providers to add specific hardware for my needs.

Comment: 1) Are you worried about handshake cost or about the bulk encryption cost? In the latter case, the protocol doesn't matter much, the choice of cipher and the implementation matter. 2) Which kind of CPU are you using? What are your performance targets?

Comment: 1) More about bulk encryption, connection setup is also of a concern but less so. Assuming that the connection can be kept up most of the time and rekeying is either not too frequent or not too expensive. 2) CPU is unknown, the app runs in public clouds.

Comment: This question is now over one year old: I stumbled about it during my research about a similar task and came to the conclusion that curvecp using the nacl library by djb (Professor Daniel J. Bernstein) has serious advantages:  Modern Linux distributions have a "ready to use" package called 'nacl-tools' containing two programs 'curvecpclient'  and 'curvecpserver' which together with the tool 'curvecpmakekey' take much of the development burden away.  So I tend to disagree somewhat with Marten Bodewes answer given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with TLS. The chances that the provider has heard of it and that acceleration is already present is rather high. SSH would also be an option, but it is generally used for administration.

About the other options:

- *UDT -- Should be high performance, how is the optional encryption?* Good question, and a quick search did not find too much information, so avoid.
- *CurveCP -- By DJB so encryption is good, not sure about the transport part* Anything mainly done by DJB requires university grade understanding of cryptography.
- *MinimaLT -- DJB contributed crypto know-how, others did the transport.* See above. The main documentation seems to be a paper about MinimalLT.
- *IPSec -- non-trivial to configure* And possibly security at the wrong level. Personally I would avoid, may be tricky to setup on a cloud provider.

So there you are, in the end transport level security always seems to gravitate towards TLS.

Try to go for a ciphersuite with AES and ECDSA/ECDH(E) if you want a high chance of a speedy implementation and a high level of security.